# What conclusion to make when multiple regression gives a relationship yet a linear regression doesn't

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I had this exercise in my class, and as it will be not corrected, I have no clue which conclusion to get.

Assume we perform a multiple linear regression, for the sake of illustration, assume we do it in R, on the dataset swiss, and we seek to find out the relationships with the fertility measure. We get as a result this:

[image]

So we see for example that there is a link between fertility measure and examination. Now if we perform a linear regression analysis on the examination measure, we get:

[image]

And here we conclude we have no correlation.

So my question is how do I interpret these results? What does it mean? Is there a relationship or not?

Comment: The question seems confused. The single-variable model shows a significant result at conventional levels and the correlation is also acceptable -- for this kind of social science, it is surprisingly good! Hence I cannot follow what you mean by "no correlation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>First of all a linear model does not make conclusions about correlations, it's about significant differences.</s> A linear model outputs are not necessarily related to correlation.

As for the two models. The second model is telling you that if you try to explain fertility only with examination there is a significant relationship between them - examination can explain some relation which is better than not having this variable.

However, if you include some additional variables in your model then examination is no longer significant, meaning that whatever effect examination had in the second model is now replaced by another variable which explains the relationship just as well or better, so examination is longer needed or related.

Comment: I am familiar with this dataset and, other way round, have used it for teaching. A little exploration of the data and a little thought about what the variables mean underlines that `Examination` and `Education` are both proxies for level of education and fight each other for market share.

Comment: Your first paragraph seems contentious to me. A linear model is about relationships between variable: what they mean and whether a linear model is the best functional form are always up for discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it really cleared up things!

Answer (score 2):

If you check for correlations between your predictors, you can see that examination and education are correlated while agriculture is anti-correlated with both of these:

```
cor(swiss[,-1])
                 Agriculture Examination   Education   Catholic
Agriculture       1.00000000  -0.6865422 -0.63952252  0.4010951
Examination      -0.68654221   1.0000000  0.69841530 -0.5727418
Education        -0.63952252   0.6984153  1.00000000 -0.1538589
Catholic          0.40109505  -0.5727418 -0.15385892  1.0000000
Infant.Mortality -0.06085861  -0.1140216 -0.09932185  0.1754959
                 Infant.Mortality
Agriculture           -0.06085861
Examination           -0.11402160
Education             -0.09932185
Catholic               0.17549591
Infant.Mortality       1.00000000

heatmap(cor(swiss),cexCol=0.7,cexRow=0.7)
```

[image]

We can visualize how Education and Examination are related to Fertility:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(swiss,aes(x=Education,y=Examination,col=Fertility)) + 
geom_point() + scale_color_viridis_c() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

So you can see that the observations that are high in fertility are low in both education and examination (yellowish dots, bottom left). If you have both of these in a linear regression, only one of them is required to predict, and the other one will be redundant. It is as @NickCox pointed out in hise comment, "both proxies for level of education and fight each other for market share".

Hence when you do a linear regression, one will take up a negative coefficient (Education in your example) and the examination will have a close to zero coefficient.

So a maybe safe answer to your question is, they are both negatively correlated to fertility, but they are predicting the same high fertility observations.

Comment: Thanks for the mention but "above" can become "below", and vice versa,  if answers change their order through voting, or just randomly, so I've edited accordingly.